# RequireJS: Not triggering require callback on specifying absolute path name for which paths alias exists in config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Here there is a paths alias "jquery" in require.js config

Require.JS is triggering require callback for "jquery" but it doesn't trigger the require callback if absolute path is specified for jquery module.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        baseUrl    : "../../",
        paths      : {
            'jquery' : '/js/jquery-1.8.3',
        },
    };
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/require.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function(obj) {
        console.info("jquery loaded","alias");
    });
    require(['jquery'],function(obj) {
        console.info("jquery loaded","alias");
    });
    require(['/js/jquery-1.8.3.js'],function(obj) {
        console.info("jquery loaded","absolute path");
    });
</script>
```

I expected console.info from the last require statement to be executed, but it doesn't trigger. Looks like if you require a path alias and then require the absolute path,it's not triggering the callback.

Is this a bug in Require.JS or any alternate ways to get callback triggered with both path alias and absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Trying to load the *same* module under two different names does not work. There's good evidence this is by design.

RequireJS treats modules as singletons. (The scope of the "singelton-ness" is a RequireJS context. So the same module could be instantiated once for a context and a second time for a *different context* but it will never be instantiated twice for the same context.) When RequireJS loads a module, the module acquires a name. If the `define` call has a string as the first argument, the name is this string. Otherwise, if there was no `map` affecting the loading of the module, the name will be the string that appeared in `require` or `define` call that the listed the module as a dependency. So, using your configuration in the question, if you do `require(['jquery'], ...` or have a module `foo` that is defined as `define(['jquery'], ...` then the name that will be given to the module found at `js/jquery-1.8.3` is `jquery`. Then there is the fact that inside a module, you get get the module name by doing something like this:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    console.log("my module name: " + module.id);
});
```

Ok, so what happens if your module is required twice with two different module names? Remember that modules are singletons so RequireJS won't execute the `define` twice. Which `id` should the module get?

In practice, it is **almost always** the case that when the same module code is being loaded under two different names, **it is an programming mistake** rather than something the developers really wanted to do. I've never run into a codebase where RequireJS was used where it would have been valid to load jQuery both as `jquery` and using a path with the version number. The latter case would indeed be an error. So rather than use some sort of default behavior that will probably lead to surprises down the road, RequireJS breaks right away when you try to load the same module under two different names. This is the safe thing to do.

Now, if you really really must be able to load the same module with two names, then you can do it but you must be explicit about what you want: you can use `map`. This will establish an unambiguous relation between the module names you want to use. What a map does is basically saying "when code in module X requires module Y load module Z instead." So in your case:

```
map: {
    '*':
        '/js/jquery-1.8.3': 'jquery'
    }
}
```

This says "when code in any module (`*`) requires `/js/jquery-1.8.3` load `jquery` instead". In case you wonder, this won't result in a circular dependency. RequireJS will see `/js/jquery-1.8.3` passed to `require` or `define`, will then inspect the `map` and convert it to `jquery`, will then find `jquery` in `paths` and convert it to `/js/jquery-1.8.3` and then add the `.js` extension and fetch the module. After it has gone through `paths` it does not go back to `map`, because the result it gets from `paths` is a path, not a module name (and `map` only transforms module names).

Note that with the map above, there is only one module loaded, which is named `jquery`. If `module.id` were used in it, it would always have the value `"jquery"` and could not have any other value.

Important side note: you should not put the `.js` in the `require` call, otherwise it won't work: `require(['/js/jquery-1.8.3'], ...`.